# Faded Palindromes runtime error

Tags: java, runtime

Its an codechef program .. Basically its running fine on my local machine and also all the online compilers i tried but codechef keeps giving me runtime error

Link - https://www.codechef.com/SEPT16/problems/LEXOPAL
please help me to get what the error is
Runtime error is RE (NZEC)

```
import java.util.*;
class Faded
{

    public static void  main (String args[])
    {
        display();
    }
    public static void display()
    {
        Scanner get=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=get.nextInt();
        String result[]= new String[n];
        String readuser[]= new String[n];
            get.nextLine();
            for(int a=0;a<n;a++)
            {
            readuser[a]=get.nextLine();
            }
        for(int a=0;a<n;a++)
        {
            result[a]=new String(readuser[a]);
            if((readuser[a].length()==3)&&(readuser[a].charAt(0)!=readuser[a].charAt(2)))
            {
            result[a]=new String("-1");
            continue;
            }

                    int res=readuser[a].indexOf(".");
                    float mid=(readuser[a].length())/2;
                    if((res==mid)||(readuser[a].length()==1))
                    {
                            result[a]=result[a].replace('.','a');
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(res==readuser[a].length()-1)
                    {
                        result[a]=result[a].replace('.',result[a].charAt(0));
                        continue;
                    }


                    if(res<readuser[a].length()/2)
                    {
                    result[a]=result[a].replace('.',result[a].charAt(readuser[a].length()-1-res));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    result[a]=result[a].replace('.',result[a].charAt(res+1));

                    }

                        }
                        for(int a=0;a<n;a++)
                    System.out.println(result[a]);
                        }
    }
```

Comment: We cannot help you unless you give us details of the runtime error.

Comment: runtime error is RE (NZEC)

Answer (score 0):

There are slight logical test cases that are needed to be satisfied when multiple "." occurs in your string. Do check that.
And regarding The resolve of NZEC Just in your display() function you need to catch an exception then that NZEC error will be gone.

And you are recomended to use BufferReader, InputStreamRreader